# query with date range condition returns empty result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query that reads some records from a table that are in a specific date range. I am using PHP under codeigniter framework and the query is pretty simple.

```
$this->db->select('aa.code,aa.employee_code ,aa.assign_date,aa.asset_serial_no');
$this->db->from('asset_assigns as aa');
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date >= $date1");
```

The above works fine!

```
$this->db->select('aa.code,aa.employee_code ,aa.assign_date,aa.asset_serial_no');
$this->db->from('asset_assigns as aa');
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date <= $date2");
```

The above also reads proper number of queries!

```
$this->db->select('aa.code,aa.employee_code ,aa.assign_date,aa.asset_serial_no');
$this->db->from('asset_assigns as aa');
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date <= $date2");
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date >= $date1");
```

But this one with two 'where' returns empty!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for date comparisions use mysql `datediff` and `timediff` functions.

```
$this->db->where("datediff(aa.assign_date,$date2) <= 0 and datediff(aa.assign_date,$date1) >= 0");
```

If you are not explicit, dates are compared as strings.  consider the two queries:

```
select date('2010/10/01') > date('2010/2/15');
```

with a date comparison you get the correct output of '1', first date is greater than second date, whereas:

```
select '2010/10/01' > '2010/2/15';
```

with a string comparison, you get '0' which is the wrong output for dates (but the right output for strings).

Comment: Yet it return 0 records! :(

Comment: after the $this->db->query(), do a 'echo $this->db->lastquery()'.  copy and paste it into mysql client and try to figure stuff out.

Comment: my bad `last_query()`  (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date <= $date2 AND aa.assign_date >= $date1");
```

Comment: Where did you set $date1 and $date2 ?

Comment: I have echoed the dates right before the query and they show the dates I want and there are alot of records in that range I am sure:function sbrns($date1, $date2){echo $date1." - ".$date2;...

Comment: try to `echo` $date1 and $date2 before your `select` statement for know if they are correct value

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are these db methods are implemented in codeignitor 
but probably you can replace;

```
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date <= $date2");
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date >= $date1");
```

with

```
$this->db->where("aa.assign_date <= $date2 AND aa.assign_date >= $date1");
```